# how to read and upload text file from server in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i've a text file on 000webhost server with url [http://file_server.comxa.com/remote_server/temp.txt][1]

i want to read first value  till delimiter,here is the code

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
$file = fopen ("http://file_server.comxa.com/remote_server/temp.txt", "r");
if (!$file) {
echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.\n";
exit;
}
while (!feof ($file)) {
$line = fgets ($file, 1024);
if (preg_match ("@\<title\>(.*)\</title\>@i", $line, $out)) {
    $title = $out[1];
    break;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `temprature` (`id`, `temprature`) VALUES (NULL, $line)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if($result)
{
    echo "temprature inserted";
}
else
{
    echo "failure";
}
}
fclose($file);  
?>
```

but this code is throwing error 
`Warning: fopen(http://file_server.comxa.com/remote_server/temp.txt): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\server_read.php on line 3
Unable to open remote file.`

Let me know where i'm wrong

P.S: its working fine when i'm changing  path to my localhost file

Comment: http://file_server.comxa.com/remote_server/temp.txt
Try to visit your url. Remove server reply is 404 Not found. So why do you expect to work in your script when this url is not accessible from anywhere at all.

Comment: actually i've uploaded temp.txt in remote_server directory,but still can't read it

Comment: Problem is neither with php, nor with mysql. It seems that you cannot access your file uploaded to hosting. Check if webserver has read access rights to this file.